# Airflow 2 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.text_processing_plugin'

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am new to `airflow` and trying to make a dag for processing text. I have a datapipeline consisting of text processing tasks - reading doc, cleaning text and loading data to JSON file. For text processing, custom operators are used for each transformation task and they are kept in `text_processing_plugin` folder. Complete folder structure of `plugin` folder is:-

```
├── airflow.cfg
├── airflow.db
├── airflow-webserver.pid
├── dags
│   ├── d0.py
├── plugins
│   └── text_processing_plugin
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── operators
│       │   ├── dependency_parsing.py
│       │   ├── entity_detection.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── lemmatize.py
│       │   ├── pos_tagging.py
│       │   ├── remove_stop_words.py
│       │   └── tokenize_doc.pyfolder structure of plugin folder is:-
├── requirements.txt
├── unittests.cfg
```

where `text_processing_plugin/__init__.py` has following code:-

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from text_processing_plugin.operators.dependency_parsing import DependencyParsingOperator 
from text_processing_plugin.operators.entity_detection import DetectEntityOperator
from text_processing_plugin.operators.lemmatize import LemmatizeOperator
from text_processing_plugin.operators.pos_tagging import POSTagOperator
from text_processing_plugin.operators.remove_stop_words import RemoveStopWordsOperator
from text_processing_plugin.operators.tokenize_doc import DocTokenizerOperator

class TextProcessingPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "text_processing_plugin"
    operators = [DependencyParsingOperator, DetectEntityOperator, LemmatizeOperator, POSTagOperator, 
        RemoveStopWordsOperator, DocTokenizerOperator]
    sensors = []
    hooks = []
    executors = []
    macros = []
    admin_views = []
    flask_blueprints = []
    menu_links = []
    appbuilder_views = []
    appbuilder_menu_items = []
    global_operator_extra_links = []
    operator_extra_links = []
```

For making DAG, `airflow 1.x` like paradigm in used like below:-

```
import os
import json
import spacy
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.operators.text_processing_plugin import DependencyParsingOperator, DetectEntityOperator, LemmatizeOperator, POSTagOperator, RemoveStopWordsOperator, DocTokenizerOperator

sp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'episource',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 30),
    'retries': 0,
    'schedule_interval':'@once',
}

dag = DAG(
    'text_processing_dag',
    description='Text Processing Dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['text_processing'])

def read_doc(**kwargs):
    file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/data/1.txt')
    doc = open(file_path).read()
    return doc

def write_to_json(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd, 'output', '1.json'), 'a+') as file:
        result_1 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'tokenize_doc')
        result_2 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'detect_entity')
        print('result 1 is ', result_1)
        print('result 2 is ', result_2)
        file.write(json.dumps(result_1))
        file.write(json.dumps(result_2))


extract = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'extract',
    python_callable = read_doc,
    dag = dag)

t11_tokenize_doc = DocTokenizerOperator(
    sp = sp,
    task_id = "transform_tokenize_doc", 
    dag = dag, 
    name = "Sentence Tokenizing",
    pool='t1',
    task_concurrency=2)

t12_detect_entities = DetectEntityOperator(
    sp = sp,
    task_id = "transform_detect_entity", 
    dag = dag, 
    name = "Entity Detection",
    pool='t1',
    task_concurrency=2)

load = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'load',
    python_callable = write_to_json,
    dag = dag)

extract >> [t11_tokenize_doc, t12_detect_entities] >> load
```

When I try to run the code, I am getting :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dags/d0.py", line 8, in <module>
    from airflow.operators.text_processing_plugin import DependencyParsingOperator, DetectEntityOperator, LemmatizeOperator, POSTagOperator, RemoveStopWordsOperator, DocTokenizerOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.text_processing_plugin'
```

I referred some existing answers on Stackoverflow, but unable to get a way around the error. Would appreciate some hint on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Changed in version **2.0**: Importing operators, sensors, hooks added in
> plugins via **airflow.{operators,sensors,hooks}.<plugin_name>** [is no
> longer supported](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html#plugins), and these extensions should just be imported as
> regular python modules. For more information, see: [Modules Management](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html)
> and [Creating a custom Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html)